# Why isn't my 'extend' working in html file in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

This is getting really irritating. I don't know what I am doing wrong and *what is wrong* because literally I get no errors. But this is the problem. My other html files in not being displayed on the main.html file. These are the three file:

1)main.html

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'tinymce/css/prism.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    {% block nav_bar %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block tutorial_blocks %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'tinymce/js/prism.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2)tutorial_blocks.html

```
{% extends 'center/main.html' %}
{% block tutorial_blocks %}
{% for x in tutorials %}
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title"><b>{{ x.tutorial_title|safe }}</b></span>
            <p><font color="black">{{ x.tutorial_content|safe }}</font></p>
            <p>Uploaded: <i>{{ x.tutorial_published }}</i></p>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

3)nav_bar.html

```
{% extends 'center/main.html' %}
{% block nav_bar %}
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Tutorials!</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Whenever I run the server I receive a blank white page.However if I do it like this, it works:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'tinymce/css/prism.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Tutorials!</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% for x in tutorials %}
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title"><b>{{ x.tutorial_title|safe }}</b></span>
            <p><font color="black">{{ x.tutorial_content|safe }}</font></p>
            <p>Uploaded: <i>{{ x.tutorial_published }}</i></p>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
<script src="{% static 'tinymce/js/prism.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the file becomes messy real quick and its not even complete yet. I would prefer using the 'extended' way, because its easier for me to edit and modify when necessary. Any help it appreciated.

Comment: What template does your view serve? If it's `main.html` the other two templates won't be included. You have to use the `include` tag for that.

Comment: @Lomtrur yes my view.py serves the main.html. Where do I use include tag?

Comment: "yes my view.py serves the main.html" => then it's obviously not going to work indeed. "Where do I use include tag? " => that's probably not the solution actually...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers then what is the solution?

Comment: That's what I was thinking about right now actually xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my view.py serves the main.html

You may want to re-read the manual then, that's not how template inheritance works. What you probably want here is to

1/ rename "center/main.html" to "center/base.html"

2/ create a new "center/main.html" template which just fills in the blocks:

```
{% extends 'center/base.html' %}

{% block tutorial_blocks %}
{% for x in tutorials %}
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title"><b>{{ x.tutorial_title|safe }}</b></span>
            <p><font color="black">{{ x.tutorial_content|safe }}</font></p>
            <p>Uploaded: <i>{{ x.tutorial_published }}</i></p>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block nav_bar %}
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Tutorials!</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
```

IOW move the content of your two other "subtemplates" here.

And now when you render "center/main.html" it should work as expected (unless there's something else wrong in your code of course).

As a side note: your may want to learn and use the `{% url %}` templatetag - hardcoding urls is a bad idea.